# GNU Fortran compiler to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I want to add GNU Fortran compiler to Visual Studio 2013. Is there any way?

I've tried Intel Parallel Studio cluster edition but the evaluation period has ended and it is so expensive.

Comment: I don't know of any way. People usually use GNU Fortran with other IDEs, like Code::Blocks or Photran. Or just with a text editor.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/202653/gfortran-with-visual-studio-2010-as-ide

Comment: You may be able to do it with VS2015.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way, but it will also cost you money: the [Lahay Compiler](http://www.lahey.com/) provides a [Visual Studio "Shell"](http://www.lahey.com/lf76/lf76.htm) which also includes `gfortran` in version 4.9.1.

Unfortunately, it's not much cheaper than Intel Parallel Studio :(